# Force a div over an auto complete

Tags: html, css, z-index

Is it possible to force an element to render above an automatic autocomplete in chrome?

A simple absolute with a z-index renders fine above the form, but autocompletes don't share the z-ordering of the form element....

I would like to retain the use of the default auto-complete (rather than 3rd party ones).   Googling suggests styling with 'webkit-autofill' might be a relevant, but doesn't seem to help.

*(I realise this is terrible UI design - you don't have to tell me about that!)*

Thanks!

[image]

```
<body>
    <form>
        <div style="position:absolute;z-index:100;width:100px;right:50px;background:#eeeeee;border:1px solid black">
            Jennifer<br>
            Alison<br>
            Phillipa<br>
            Sue<br>
        </div>
        <input id="id1" name="test" style="width:100%">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: No, you can't force the browser to autocomplete. You should use JavaScript .

Comment: as @paolo.basso99 mentioned, no you can not. but what is important here is the different between the _native browser autocomplete_ functionality and the _3rd party ajax autocomplete_ functionality. are you aware of the difference between them?

Comment: So you say you want both the default (browser suggestions) auto complete and also the 3rd party plugin auto complete??

Comment: A 3rd part script is enouth however you should never turn off the browser autocomplete for the best user experience.